# How to store image in a database using laravel and then display it

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've seen some topics on stack about this question but none of them are exactly what i want. Mostly people are saying it's a bad idea to store image in a database. I know it but still I need to save an image in a database and be able to display it. please provide a code or some video how to do it. thanks in advance

Comment: Just search on google and you will find the solution [https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-how-do-you-save-image-to-database-and-display-it-on-website](https://laravel.io/forum/02-17-2014-how-do-you-save-image-to-database-and-display-it-on-website)

Comment: I would say the best way would be to store the image in a relative path, best to be structured depending on your application, and then just store the relative path in your database.

Comment: agreed, you almost certainly don't _need_ to save the image in the database. Save the image file to the disk on the server and then in the database store the path and filename of the image.

Comment: show what you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

for storing it on database first get content of the file

```
$File = Input::file('File');
$FileContent = $File->openFile()->fread($File->getSize());
```

save the content of file on your database with base64_encode:

```
$databaseModel->create([
                   'FileContent' => base64_encode($FileContent),
                   'ContentType' => $File->getMimeType()
                ]);
```

then retrieve it from database and return it with the following code:

```
$response = Response::make(base64_decode($databaseModel->FileContent), 200);
$response->header('Content-Type', $databaseModel->ContentType);
return $response
```